# LINQ-to-Entities Where clause with OR condition?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am programmatically setting the Where clause on a EntityDataSource like so:

```
edsCheckListEntities.Where = "not it.business_done"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't catch any null values, which also are "not done" so I tried the following:

```
edsCheckListEntities.Where = "it.business_done is nothing or not it.business_done"
```

But this throws an error. Is there a way to do an OR like this in an entity data source where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* you just want to use ["is null"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399793.aspx) instead of "is nothing":

```
edsCheckListEntities.Where = "it.business_done is null or not it.business_done"
```

(I haven't used any Entity SQL, but I'm just going from the documentation.)